# how to save checkbox data for custom setting?

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, admin-menu, settings-api

I am creating one custom setting panel, my codes are

```
function custom_text_field_html(){
 
    $text = get_option( 'homepage_text' );
 
    printf(
        '<input type="text" id="homepage_text" name="homepage_text" value="%s" />',
        esc_attr( $text )
    );
 
}

function custom_checkbox_field_html(){
 
    $checkbox = get_option( 'disabletitle_text' );
 
    printf(
        '<input type="checkbox" id="disabletitle_text" name="disabletitle_text" value="1" />',
        esc_attr( $checkbox )
    );
 
}
```

my checkbox data is not saving, how to save checkbox data like 'text field', so that I can call them in functions, if someone checked the field 'enable that function', if someone 'not checked the field', disable the function.

I referred this http://qnimate.com/add-checkbox-using-wordpress-settings-api/, but it's showing error in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkbox data is saved as `1` or `''` if someone checked or unchecked it.

you can also verify this using `var_dump($checkbox)` inside `custom_checkbox_field_html` function

This should work.

```
function custom_checkbox_field_html(){
 
    $checkbox = get_option( 'disabletitle_text' );
    $is_checked = (  $checkbox != '' && $checkbox == 1 ) ? 'checked': '';

    printf(
        '<input type="checkbox" id="disabletitle_text" name="disabletitle_text" value="1" %s/>',
        esc_attr( $is_checked )
    );
 
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. Can you answer the second question- How can I call them in functions, if someone checked the field 'enable that function', if someone 'not checked the field', disable the function. for example after check, disable updates. Thanks :)

Comment: just use this `get_option( 'disabletitle_text' )` value to determine you needs. if it return `1` then you can enable you function else you can disable your function.